# Which way is best for making a public variable for every visitor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, button, public

I am trying to get everyone's  total clicks on a button. I was thinking about POST function with ajax but it would make lots of PHP request on the server. I want to do something like that:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('buttonToClick').onclick = function() {
    var totalClicks = ???; // get total clicks number from the server somehow and 
// assign it to var totalClicks;

    document.getElementById("totalClicks").innerHTML = totalClicks;

    ??? = ??? + 1; // add 1 to total clicks number and save it to server.
}​;​
</script>

<input id="buttonToClick" type="submit" name="button" value="enter"/>
<a>The button is clicked <a id="totalClicks"></a> times!</a>
```

Is it possible to make this with Javascript?

Comment: websockets are slightly more complicated to set up, but wouldn't fire off a separate request for each click.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use AJAX to `POST` the data to the server, since you are using jQuery you can use the `$.ajax` function.

As an example:

```
$(document).on("click", "#buttonToClick", function() {
   uploadClickCount();
});

function uploadClickCount()
{
    var userId = $("#UserId").val(); // Get the user id first
    var totalClicks = $("#totalClicks").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'YourWebsite/ClickCounter',
        type: "POST",
        data: { user: userId, clickCount: totalClicks },
        success: function() { }
        error: function() { alert('Unable to connect to the server'); }
    });
}
```

An alternative to save on calls to the server would be to attempt to send the total clicks when the user leaves the page or closes the page using the `window.unload` method, however this may be unreliable.

You could also look at storing the click count in `HTML 5` local storage and then upload it when the user returns/once the `DOM` is ready, i.e.. `$(document).ready(function() { });`

It would also be best practice to store when the user last attempted to contact the server, you can then use this to invoke the AJAX call after a 10 second delay which would prevent mass requests server side.

Comment: you should point out that even if the user clicked a 100 items that this would for the vast majority of sites not stress it in the least.